# unable to import spss module in watson studio

Tags: watson-studio, spss-modeler

I am trying to import the built in spss module for Time Forecasting.

But I am receiving the following error on running the import command in watson notebook

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 from spss.ml.forecasting.timeseriesexploration import TimeSeriesExploration

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spss'

Please let me know what resolution can be done or if any step needs to be done before import.

On running the command !pip install com.ibm.spss, the following error gets displayed

Collecting com.ibm.spss
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement com.ibm.spss (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for com.ibm.spss

Answer (score 0):

Notebooks and SPSS modeller are two distinct features of Watson Studio, which use separate backends to run your computations. The SPSS modeller code is not installed in the Notebook runtimes. Neither is it open source code on PyPI, so you cannot install it with `pip`.

To use built-in SPSS modules, you have to work with the SPSS modeller feature instead of the Notebooks feature.

Comment: How can we implement the following example for time forecasting in IBM Watson

https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/spss/forecasting-guides.html